# Change Kubernetes log format to json at create or runtime?

Tags: json, kubernetes, logging

I would like to change the default Kubernetes log format to "json" for system logs at "create" or preferably at "runtime".

The documentation designates the `--logging-format=json` for this purpose. However, I have been unable to identify what command-line call I would use to specific this flag.

I have tried `kube-apiserver` and `kind` cmd-line with no luck so far.

I am currently using [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/), but any reference related to Kube would be fine.

Questions:

1. Does this need be at "create" for the cluster?
2. If runtime is ok, what cmd util would I use to change a cluster configuration at runtime?
3. Do I need to apply a configuration with "kubectl" with a `yaml` file?

Comment: I replicated it on minikube. I used command `minikube start --extra-config scheduler.logging-format=json` which I found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9268#issuecomment-889582602) to start a cluster and when I checked logs there were in JSON format. I couldn't find is it possible during `runtime`. Is your cluster used for production or for test only and you are able recreate a cluster?

Comment: It is for test, so no problem tearing down the cluster. That minikube command is def a help. That said I haven't found a similar option for kind yet.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-instrumentation/1602-structured-logging#production-readiness-review-questionnaire) you can read more about switching between text (original) and json (new) log formats. Let me know if it will help you with your Kind cluster